# Anti Sniper / anti Snipe Bot for newly listed token on pancakeswap

Tags: contract-development, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

Can Somebody explain how to have Bot Protection enabled against sniper bot for a token contract which is going to launch on pancakeswap or on any other decentralised exchange.

do we have to create smart contract to tackle sniper bot from dumping liquidty?

Comment: Your token can have a time lock that prevents selling (moving tokens to certain addresses) in the smart contract code.

Comment: do you mean by token contract if not then is there any way to do this bot protection enabled for existing token contract?

Comment: If you want to execute fair launch for your token, then you do it on a launchpad that sells the token for a fixed price to build the initial liquidity. You cannot do a fair launch on DEX.